# C# different model ordering

Tags: c#, .net, api

I have 3 different models which share about 4 attributes. Models aren't connected in any way nor do they extend or implement anything. I have Angular 4 front which is sending a string of a column by which ordering should take place.

Now the method I have here works, but there must be a smarter and shorter way to do it:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResponseTime> orderBy(ApiResponseTime apiResponseTime, IEnumerable<ApiResponseTime> returnList)
    {
        switch (apiResponseTime.order_by_value)
        {
            case "id":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.id);
            break;

            case "!id":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.id);
            break;

            case "tenant_id":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.tenant_id);
            break;

            case "!tenant_id":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.tenant_id);
            break;

            case "start_time":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.start_time);
            break;

            case "!start_time":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.start_time);
            break;

            case "total_time":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.total_time);
            break;

            case "!total_time":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.total_time);
            break;

            case "status_code":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.status_code);
            break;

            case "!status_code":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.status_code);
            break;

            case "api_endpoint_route":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.api_endpoint_route);
            break;

            case "!api_endpoint_route":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.api_endpoint_route);
            break;

            case "requesting_ip":
            returnList = returnList.OrderBy(x => x.requesting_ip);
            break;

            case "!requesting_ip":
            returnList = returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.requesting_ip);
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

My first idea was somehow "translating" string to column name, but I read that that was a bad idea, and I should utilize the strongly typed language. Is there some lambda I can do in order to make this work? Possibly instead only one string send 2, where other value will be asc/desc?

Comment: The obvious shortening I see is to set a boolean to represent the existence of '!' in the 'order_by_value' string, trim the "!" from it and remove all the cases where there is 'case "!...' Then, if the boolean is true,  reverse the 'returnList' list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue, you could shorten it by..

```
...
case "id" : return returnList.OrderBy(x => x.id);
case "!id": return returnList.OrderByDescending(x => x.id);
...
```

If they are linqToSql queries you can do .OrderBy("ColumnName DESC")

Comment: Sure, but that technically isn't what I need. I was looking more into something like `returnList.OrderBy(x => x.WhereColumnName(string)`

Comment: If they are linqToSql queries you can do .OrderBy("ColumnName DESC")

Comment: this works with `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` package, though it has no option for forwarding "DESC" as a parameter, but I can do that with if-else. Just modify the answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit cleaner to use two enums: field and direction.

```
public enum Field
{
    Id,
    TenantId,
    StartTime,
    ...
}

public enum Direction
{
    Ascending,
    Descending,
}

public IEnumerable<T> Sort<T, KEY>(IEnumerable<T> l, Direction d, Func<T, KEY> getKey)
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case Direction.Ascending:  return l.OrderBy(getKey);
        case Direction.Descending: return l.OrderByDescending(getKey);
        default:                   return l;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<ApiResponseTime> orderBy(Field f, Direction d, IEnumerable<ApiResponseTime> l)
{
    switch (f)
    {
        case Field.Id:         return Sort(l, d, x => x.id);
        case Field.StartTime:  return Sort(l, d, x => x.start_time);

        // and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better you build orderby expression which will take a parameter as string and order by that property. This will remove your switch and make your code more generic.

 
`public static IQueryable OrderByProperty(this IQueryable source, string orderByPropertyName){
    ParameterExpression paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
    Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(paramterExpression, orderByPropertyName);
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, paramterExpression);
    MethodInfo genericMethod = OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (T), orderByProperty.Type);
    return (IQueryable)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});

 }`



Now remove your switch case and call like

```
returnList.OrderByProperty(apiResponseTime.order_by_value)
```